# VBA serial port received data conversion to bytes

Tags: excel, vba

I try to communicate with a device via COM port in an Excel VBA script using "modCOMM - Written by: David M. Hitchner".

I have trouble reading the received data correctly and hope that someone can help me with it.
The data i receive when looking at it with a port monitor software is:

```
09 ff 01 95 31 2e 32 39 76
```

while the data I read in VBA looks like this (converting the string to bytes again):

```
09 00 FF 00 01 00 22 20 31 00 2E 00 32 00 39 00 76 00
```

Does someone have an idea how I need to convert the (18) bytes to get the expected 9 bytes above? With most bytes it seems like the "correct" byte followed by byte with 0, but for bytes 7-10 (`22 20 31 0` -> `95 31`) it's different.

Serial port monitor of received data:

[image]

Comment: Apparently you have used a `string` somewhere where you should have used a byte array. Please show the code. The undoing conversion is `StrConv(that_string, vbFromUnicode)`, but the actual fix is to not get to that situation in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i indeed used a string, due to using "modCOMM - Written by: David M. Hitchner" (or atleast the fork from https://gist.github.com/heiswayi/f47dfd8dc38955322bef ) <br/> i used CommRead function which returned a string. I just tried the StrConv and it's working, but i guess you are correct and i should just change the CommRead function instead. Thank you for your help!